# My tables just won't line up. There's a gap between the inside and outside table?

Tags: html

This link [shows the problem when the page loads](http://genafterdc.com/Template.html).
It's http://genafterdc.com/Template.html.  There's no code I can spot that's creating the space.

This has become an ongoing problem that I can't get tables to line up, and gaps exist at the top.  So this will solve a lot of problems and wasted time and work arounds for me.

The code is:

```
<table width="78%" border="1">
<tr> 
  <td width="15%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="41%" height="471"> 
   <table width="100%" border="2" height="242">
    <tr> 
      <td height="204" valign="top">Not at top -- gap shows from top 
     of table to this table.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div align="right"> </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td width="1%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="42%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="1%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
```

(another table row was removed from the code for readablity)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table width="78%" border="1">
<tr> 
  <td width="15%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="41%" height="471" valign ="top"> 
   <table width="100%" border="2" height="242">
    <tr> 
      <td height="204" valign="top">Not at top -- gap shows from top 
     of table to this table.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div align="right"> </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td width="1%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="42%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="1%" height="471">&nbsp;</td>
```

You were just missing a valign="top" in the fourth line. See fixed code above

Comment: Wow, how did you spot it so quickly?  (Really how?).  I had to comment out a bunch to spot where it was missing from. Also, in an esoteric world -- I was typing my answer just as you were.  Maybe you spotted it, and that's when the idea finally floated into my brain from yours?  Anyway -- thankyou!!!

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster here --

I think I've solved it for this case.  I added a valign="top" to a TD tag.  I commented out nested tables and every else, and found a tag that sent with another box in the table in the same row that also wasn't letting things go to the top.  Adding the valign seems to have fixed both.  So I new about valign, but I think haven't been finding the right TD to stick it on. At least in this case.  I'm not sure in the other case I couldn't solve.  I need to go look.

Hopefully valign isn't downgraded by any of the browsers and will work when on TD tag with all of them.